# In objective c from a float number I want to sepatate the decimals to do further math work on

Tags: objective-c, math, xcode4, decimal

I am setting up a calculator that will generate a float number after the user's input. As an example: if the answer generated is 1.75 that would actually represents 1.75 hours. I want to split the answer into two parts to read 1 hr. 45 min which will be more user friendly than .75 of an hour is.

So I need to be able to delete the whole digit(s) (in this example the "1") before the decimal to get a variable value using the .75 --kind of like this:

mIn = (.75 * 60) which would give me the 45 minutes value to put in my...

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@% hr. @% min", hRs, mIn];` type of statement

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly do not want to use a `float` to store a user-entered number, particularly for a calculator. This will lead to decimal/binary rounding errors that will drive you crazy. You want to use `NSDecimalNumber` for this kind of work.

The other answers here will work, but you want to replace `floor()` with `decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:`. You'll use an `NSDecimalNumberHandler` with a rounding mode of `NSRoundDown` and an appropriate `scale` (probably 2 or 3 for your purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Use `floor(floatValue)` to get the integer portion, subtract that from the floatValue to get the decimal portion.

Ex:

```
float floatValue = 1.75;
float integerPortion = floor(floatValue);
float decimalPortion = floatValue - integerPortion;

NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f hr. %.0f min", integerPortion, decimalPortion * 60];
NSLog(@"timeString: %@", timeString);
```

NSLog output:

```
timeString: 1 hr. 45 min
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the floating value to an int and subtract that from the value or you can floor it.

```
float time = 1.75;
int minutes = (time - (int)time) * 60; //or (time - floor(time)) * 60;

NSLog(@"Time: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hr. %d min", (int)time, minutes]);
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm fairly new to xcode... and I know a bit about what a cast is (never used one) and I don't understand the term "floor". Would it be possible for a brief discrption of each as they apply . Is the example you have shown cast?

Comment: floor() is a c library function: round to largest integral value not greater than the number.

Comment: Casts perform in two manners, it would be best to get a "C" language book and study it, Objective-C is "C" with additions.